# is the gcloud pubsub python client thread safe when running on grpc?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I know that running on httplib2 is not thread safe but are the Client, Topic and Subscription objects of the google-cloud-pubsub python client thread safe when using grpc in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be thread safe

source: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3272)